# Why does my convert.todouble throws an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, type-conversion

I created a GUI and the `ValueBox.Text` is the string "randomstring". What I want to do is:

if the `ValueBox.Text` has numbers *only*  `double valueLenght = Convert.ToDouble(ValueBox.Text);` else if it has characters && numbers or only characters, then I thought that from MSDN that Convert.ToDouble(string) would return 0. Which is not the case here. The code goes to :

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Then gives an exception from `mscorlib`

Comment: If this is about `Convert.ToDouble()`, why'd you post the `Dispose()`?

Comment: @Prayos

I'm just saving it goes there, nothing more.
I'm a new programmer

Comment: By "goes there" do you mean that's the code executed next in the sequence while debugging?

Comment: @JYelton  Yes, sorry if I wasnt clear enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) throws an exception if it cannot convert a string to a number.

You likely want to try [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx). The return value will be `true` if the conversion succeeded, and `false` if not. The `out double` parameter receives the result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert assumes that the object you are converting *is* able to be converted. If it is not, an exception is thrown. Use `tryParse()` with the object type that you want instead:

```
string text = "asdsad";
double d;
if (!double.TryParse(text, out d))
{
     // Not a double
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are debugging and discovering that after the `Convert.ToDouble` exception, the only thing left in your program is the disposal of the form/resources.

As others have suggested, you may want to use `Double.TryParse` instead, because now you can use its boolean output to determine if the text box contained a (successfully parsed) number or not:

```
double myDouble;
if (Double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out myDouble))
{
    // Successful conversion
}
else
{
    // Conversion failed
}
```

This is better than relying on a `Convert` exception. If you use `try/catch` to determine the outcome of something, it's not only slower, but considered bad practice.